# REST Streaming JSON Output

Tags: java, json, output, streaming, jax-rs

We have JAX RS implementation which needs to send back JSON output. But the response size is huge. And the client expects the same synchronously.
Hence I tried to use StreamingOutput... but the client is not really getting the data in chunks.
Below is sample snippet:

## Server Side

```
streamingOutput = new StreamingOutput() {

    @Override
    public void write(OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = mapper.getFactory().createGenerator(out);
        jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();
        for(int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
            jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();

            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("Response_State", "Response State - " + i);
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("Response_Report", "Response Report - " + i);
            jsonGenerator.writeStringField("Error_details", "Error Details - " + i);

            jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();;
            jsonGenerator.flush();

            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();

        jsonGenerator.close();

    }
};

return Response.status(200).entity(streamingOutput).build();
```

## Client

```
HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/AccessData/FetchReport");
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
ResponseHandler<HttpResponse> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonRequest); //jsonRequest is       request string
post.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
BufferedReader buffReader = new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonFactory().createParser(buffReader);
while(jsonParser.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_OBJECT) {
    System.out.println(jsonParser.getCurrentName() + ":" +      jsonParser.getCurrentValue());
}
String output;
while((output = buffReader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

In the server side code, I am putting sleep call just to simulate a gap between chunks of data. What I need is that the client should receive chunks of data as and when it is thrown back by the server.
But here the client gets the response in entirety always.
Any possible solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like the client side is not implemented correctly: reading the array of the objects using the parser.

Also, I would like to recommend reading and writing a data transfer object instead of low level field-by-field reading and writing.

For the sake of completeness, here is a complete **draft** example that uses: Jersey 2.25.1, Jetty 9.2.14.v20151106.

## Common

### `ResponseData` class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class ResponseData {
    private final String responseState;
    private final String responseReport;
    private final String errorDetails;

    @JsonCreator
    public ResponseData(
        @JsonProperty("Response_State") final String responseState,
        @JsonProperty("Response_Report") final String responseReport,
        @JsonProperty("Error_details") final String errorDetails) {
        this.responseState = responseState;
        this.responseReport = responseReport;
        this.errorDetails = errorDetails;
    }

    public String getResponseState() {
        return this.responseState;
    }

    public String getResponseReport() {
        return this.responseReport;
    }

    public String getErrorDetails() {
        return this.errorDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(
            "ResponseData: responseState: %s; responseReport: %s; errorDetails: %s",
            this.responseState,
            this.responseReport,
            this.errorDetails
        );
    }
}
```

## Service

### `ServerProgram` class

```
import java.net.URI;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.JacksonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jetty.JettyHttpContainerFactory;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

public class ServerProgram {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final URI uri = URI.create("http://localhost:8080/");
        final ResourceConfig resourceConfig = new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class);
        resourceConfig.register(JacksonFeature.class);
        JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(uri, resourceConfig);
    }
}
```

### `TestResource` class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.StreamingOutput;

@Path("/")
public class TestResource {
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getData() {
        final StreamingOutput streamingOutput = new JsonStreamingOutput();
        return Response.status(200).entity(streamingOutput).build();
    }

    private static class JsonStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {
        @Override
        public void write(final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final JsonFactory jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();
            try (final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = jsonFactory.createGenerator(outputStream)) {
                jsonGenerator.writeStartArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    final ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData(
                        "Response State - " + i,
                        "Response Report - " + i,
                        "Error Details - " + i
                    );
                    jsonGenerator.writeObject(responseData);
                    jsonGenerator.flush();

                    try {
                        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                jsonGenerator.writeEndArray();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Client

### `ClientProgram` class

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonToken;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientProperties;

public class ClientProgram {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
        Client client = null;
        try {
            client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
            client.property(ClientProperties.READ_TIMEOUT, 10000);

            try (final InputStream inputStream = client
                .target("http://localhost:8080/")
                .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(InputStream.class);
                final BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream)) {
                processStream(bufferedInputStream);
            }
        } finally {
            if (client != null) {
                client.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void processStream(final InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final JsonFactory jsonFactory = objectMapper.getFactory();
        try (final JsonParser jsonParser = jsonFactory.createParser(inputStream)) {
            final JsonToken arrayToken = jsonParser.nextToken();
            if (arrayToken == null) {
                // TODO: Return or throw exception.
                return;
            }

            if (!JsonToken.START_ARRAY.equals(arrayToken)) {
                // TODO: Return or throw exception.
                return;
            }

            // Iterate through the objects of the array.
            while (JsonToken.START_OBJECT.equals(jsonParser.nextToken())) {
                final ResponseData responseData = jsonParser.readValueAs(ResponseData.class);
                System.out.println(responseData);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks indeed for elaborated sample. However, what I am noticing is that the client program doesn't get the first submit from the server side immediately. It is only after some 30 odd submits from the server side that the client receives messages. And if I increase the message size, then client doesn't need to wait that much, but it still has to wait. Any idea on this? Seems some kind of buffering problem although that should not happen as the code is flushing after write... Thanks.

Comment: @SoumenGhosh, it is interesting. Maybe it would be better to ask it as a separate question?